# How should i remove a tabbaritem from in TabbarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How should i remove a tabbarItem from UITabbar Controller, When i try do this, the whole tabbar removed instead of single  tabbarItem remove?

Sri

Comment: How are you trying to do this? Please post relevant piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `-(void)setViewControllers:(NSArray*)viewContorllers animated:(BOOL)animated` method.

From documentation about this method:

*When you assign a new set of view controllers runtime, the tab bar controller removes all of the old view controllers before installing the new ones. When changing the view controllers, the tab bar controller remembers the view controller object that was previously selected and attempts to reselect it. If the selected view controller is no longer present, it attempts to select the view controller at the same index in the array as the previous selection. If that index is invalid, it selects the view controller at index 0.*

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarController/setViewControllers:animated: